# Save the live video from the webcam on the server

Tags: php, html, webrtc, webcam, recordrtc

I want to upload to the server the video that recorded by the webcam. Now what I do is record the video and once the recording is finished upload the whole, I use to record `RecordRTC`. I use HTML5 and JavaScript. What I want is to upload while recording.

Does anyone know how I can upload the video and save it on the server while recording?

I do not want to use Flash.

Comment: It is not related to webrtc in any way!

Comment: @SimonMarquis I think yes, on this site (https://github.com/webrtc/samples) there are several examples of WebRTC and think it might be useful to me

Answer (score 0):

you'd just send the data to the server in mediaRecorder.ondataavailable (assuming that recordrtc is compatible with the standard api as [demoed here](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/getusermedia/record/js/main.js)) event instead of buffering and concatenating it in the client at the end of the recording.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebRTC to stream the video/audio data to a media server like [Kurento](https://www.kurento.org/) which can act as a WebRTC endpoint and save the video to a .webm file on the disk.

We use a similar setup at [Pipe](https://addpipe.com) to power Flash free video recording in Chrome.